# Rake db:seed doubling users

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have really stupid problem with rake db:seed.

I created couple of users and seed a database with rake db:seed. When I visit my app, all users are doubled! Obviously I run rake db:reset before every attempt to seed. I restarted served. What's happening?

Answer (score 5):

By default, `rake db:reset` will also run `db:seed`, so there's no need to run both commands.

[This article](http://jacopretorius.net/2014/02/all-rails-db-rake-tasks-and-what-they-do.html) describes the full list of `db:` rake commands, which you might find helpful for future reference.